# How does one handle zero datetime in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

There are '0000-00-00 00:00:00' values in my data. How do I handle them?

I get the following error;

```
ValueError: ('Unable to parse 0000-00-00 00:00:00', u'occurred at index 1008'))
```

Reading from csv, I did this;

`pd.to_datetime(data['Deadline Time'])` 
 `pd.to_datetime(data['Completed Time'])`

and with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17896469/1948860), I did this;

```
def func(x,y):
  if x > y:
    return 'delayed by ' + str( ((x-y).seconds//60)%60) + ' minutes'
  else:
    return 'on time by ' + str( ((y-x).seconds//60)%60) + ' minutes'
data['time delay'] = data.apply(lambda row: func(pd.Timestamp(row['Completed Time']), pd.Timestamp(row['Deadline Time'])), axis=1)
```

Comment: what's your expected out for that value?

Comment: If 'Deadline' is '7/17/2012 18:24' and 'End Time' turns out to be '0000-00-00 00:00:00' I honestly don't know what that would return. As I understand, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not parsable in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, that value will be converted to a NaT

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Deadline Time'], coerce=True)
```

Comment: I get `to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coerce'`

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: It's the feature of 0.12 which just released last week.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Guess its upgrade time then!

Answer (score 0):

Just updating @waitingkuo answer, for later pandas versions.

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Deadline Time'], errors='coerce')
```